# How is $e^x$ defined as continuous continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I know the mathematical proof that: $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)$
and it is indeed works with $f(x) = e^x$
However - physically, when you talk about 'continuous functions' you are saying that you can 'draw/sktch them without removing the pencil from the page' - but in this case, where would you even start drawing? because it extends to both sides infinitely.. ? Same thing for, well $f(x) =x$  you can't be drawing the whole function without removing your pen because it extends to both sides ($x \rightarrow -\infty$) and ($x \rightarrow+\infty$)

Comment: "Continuous" basically means, generally, that at not point in the function is there a break or jump, hence the "without removing your pencil heuristic". More specifically, "sufficiently small changes in the input of a continuous function result in arbitrarily small changes in its output".

Comment: The formal definition of continuity does not involve pencils.

Comment: That pencil stuff is also misleading in another way, namely that if there are points where the function is undefined (like $x=0$ for $f(x)=1/x$, which is a continuous function since it's continuous at every point where it's defined), then you're not allowed to draw any value at that point, so you **must** lift the pencil from the paper in order to draw the graph.

Comment: @HansLundmark or $(x+3)(x-2)/(x-2)$ which doesn't even blow up at $x=2$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector That was incredibly rude. Believe it or not in public school in the United States this is the ***only*** definition of continuity offered. I’m embarrassed that you would shun a mathematical novice to a different site like that and blatantly mock him/her. Egregious.

Comment: @ gen-z ready to perish Math isn't about pencils, that's a fact (ok, there is a mathematical concept "pencil", but... forget it). Blame public schools, then, don't blame me (of course, I won't call your behavior "rude", that would be silly).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to keep caution to the following points:

1. Continuity is a local property.
2. There is a difference between the intuition behind continuity and the real definition. The definition is
   $$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists\delta>0,\ 0<\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert < \epsilon $$